# haproxy - URL redirect with same path

Tags: haproxy

i need redirect http://example1.com/goofy in http://example2.com/goofy, I already use this line:

```
redirect location http://example2.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i example1.com }
```

In this way if I go on http://example1.com/goofy I am redirect to http://example2.com and not http://example2.com/goofy, can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pathq` fetch from haproxy 2.2 will do this nicely:

```
redirect location http://example2.com%[pathq] code 301 if { hdr(host) -i example1.com }
```

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#7.3.6-pathq